# Android ProgressDialog with setContentView

Tags: android, imageview, progressdialog, custom-view

I've read a hell of a lot about this, and can't see anyone who's done or tried it before.

So I've got an object that extends ImageView, then within this I call a progress dialog and set the progress dialogs's content to the imageview (i.e. attempting to draw the progress dialog in the imageview..view.)

```
    loadingProgressDialog.setContentView(this); //this is: LoaderImageView extends ImageView        
    loadingProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    loadingProgressDialog.show();
```

And I get the error: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Now I've seen this error before on loads of posts and yes the answer seems obvious. I've tried to set all the features:

```
loadingProgressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
loadingProgressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
loadingProgressDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
loadingProgressDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

But first I don't understand why I need this? And second none of them work anyway!

So the question is can I set the ProgressDialog contentView to an ImageView? If so what have I gotten wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

The clue was in the class names, don't use ProgressDialog ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html ) when you don't need a dialog!

I changed my implementation to use: ProgressBar ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html ) and it works great.

Cheers for the ear anyway!

This is why I was looking for it for:

http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/imageview-with-loading-spinner-t49439.html

Tutorial showing how you can have a Spinner whilst an image is loading. Enjoy

Answer (score 44):

I made it;
in fact, it's very easy; using

```
loadingProgressDialog.setContentView(this)
```

after

```
loadingProgressDialog.show()
```

The following lines of code are unnecessary:

```
loadingProgressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
loadingProgressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
loadingProgressDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
loadingProgressDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

that's to say:

```
loadingProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
loadingProgressDialog.show();
loadingProgressDialog.setContentView(this); //this is: LoaderImageView extends ImageView
```

that is enough.

I hope this can help other people looking for answer about this question.

Comment: Strange, putting setContentView() AFTER .show() got it to work in my situation.  Interesting.  Thanks!

Comment: Whaao! Could never have guessed that setContentView be placed after .show()

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the progressDialog developer doc it says "A dialog showing a progress indicator and an optional text message or view. Only a text message or a view can be used at the same time."

It looks like you are trying to do both.  Possibly the cause of your issue.

Comment: I can see what your saying, this doesn't seem to be the error I've updated the original post. I got my idea from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog