# Setting/adding custom content view for ProgressDialog: requestfeature() must be called

Tags: android

So I would like to add a custom imageview to a ProgressDialog:

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
ProgressDialog pdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
pdialog.setTitle("Wait");
pdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pdialog.addContentView((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageV3iew1), root.getLayoutParams());
pdialog.setCancelable(false);
pdialog.show();
```

It says that the specified child already has a parent and I have to call removeView on the parent first. I know how to create custom dialogs but I would like to append my imageview right to the ProgressDialog. What kind of feature do I need to request?

Comment: Wait, is there supposed to be a difference between the two pieces of code you pasted? I can't see it.

Comment: I edited the post, look it again. I messed it up first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a progress dialog. Checkout this [post](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/imageview-with-loading-spinner-t49439.html) to see why. For more details, checkout this [StackoverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4351204/527288).

Comment: So I'll have to just use Dialog? How to make it look like ProgressDialog (any way finding it from android.R.layout or something)? I can make a custom dialog with my image but it looks ugly.

Comment: Yea, you'll just have to implement your own dialog because the progress dialog layout is fixed apparently.

Comment: That sucks. The Android SDK is just teasing me for having that addView method available for ProgressDialog.

Comment: Well in all fairness, the addContentView is up in the Dialog class. That said, one could definitely make the argument that it's bad API design for methods valid parent classes to not be valid in children classes.

Comment: I was so hoping there was a way for doing this. Creating custom dialogs sucks.

Comment: I know I am late* But to find the progress dialog layout look in your sdks path.. For me it was android-sdks/platforms/android-19/data/res/layout. But you can choose any api above 11 to get progress_dialog_holo

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Check out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10070995/1487456

Basically, you need to call `.show()` before you call `.setContentView()` and therefore probably `.addContentView()` also.

You can then inflate a layout and customise it however you wish.

Comment: This works and should probably be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are trying to load a view that is currently displayed in your activity into the dialog. If this is not the case that is why you are getting the null pointer. When you use findViewById the view you are looking for must be in the current activity. I think that you might want to use [layout inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to load the new view from a layout file.

I might be a bit confused on what you are trying to accomplish though.

Comment: Edited the post. Should be easier to understand now.