# Show progressDialog on fragment BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, progressdialog

I have a fragment with some fields that the user has to fill. Lets say for example the telephone number.
When the user enters the number, the fragment calls a method from MainActivity and there are some operations done in the mainActivity, let's suppose:

1- Verification

2- Validation

I use a BroadcarstReceiver to communicate back from the MainActivity to the Fragment. So when the verification is done, I send a flag to the fragment using the BroadcastReceiver to show to the user a progressDialog.

At this point, the progressDialog should show until another flag for validation is received.

The problem is that I'm getting some kind of error about RuntimeException and the app is crashing at the point where it should show the progressDialog.

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        ...

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);

        ...

        return rootView;
    }

    protected BroadcastReceiver ActivityDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(ACTION_INTENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        if(ACTION_INTENT2.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the logcat shows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.detgsm, PID: 21736
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:398)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:249)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423)
    at android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:249)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:578)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:314)
    at com.detgsm.ProfileFragment$7.onReceive(ProfileFragment.java:271)
    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Hey you cant show progress Dialog in Broadcast Receiver.Possible duplicate of
[Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766739/show-an-alert-dialog-in-broadcast-receiver-after-a-system-reboot)

Comment: You can't **create** progress dialog in BR. If you have a reference to that object. You can show it.

Comment: @mallaudin How could I then show a progressDialog in that Fragment when I receive the flag from the BR?

Comment: wait a sec.....

Comment: @masmic see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** set `contentView` before showing progress dialog. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842327/setting-adding-custom-content-view-for-progressdialog-requestfeature-must-be)

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351204/android-progressdialog-with-setcontentview).

Comment: I've just solved. In the link there is an answer that says: 
"Basically, you need to call .show() before you call .setContentView() and therefore probably .addContentView() also." If you edit your answer with this info I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

**please change to below code**

```
   public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);


}

protected BroadcastReceiver ActivityDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(ACTION_INTENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
              progressDialog.show();
              }
         });
    }
    if(ACTION_INTENT2.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is not allowing to add runOnUiThread that way to onCreateView

Comment: Let me ask one thing. Where are you registering brodacast reciver

Comment: In onCreate(). Anyway, I've just solved reading the link posted above