# Showing an image in dialog displays nothing

Tags: android, dialog

In my app I have a button which when cancelled should display a dialog which contains only an image and nothing else. The image is retrieved from a URL. But when button is clicked nothing is displayed.

My code

```
public void onClick(View v){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SingleItemView.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    ImageView imgvw = new ImageView(SingleItemView.this);
    String imgurl =descImgOne;
    Uri imguri = Uri.parse(imgurl);
    imgvw.setImageURI(imguri);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.SmileWindow;
    dialog.addContentView(imgvw, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

     dialog.show();
}
```

Where descImgOne is assigned a URL link

Comment: you have image url in this dialog?

Comment: @Er.RakeshPrajapat I assigned URL it as a global variable descImgOne

Comment: imgurl from http or local ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void onClick(View v){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SingleItemView.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);

    ImageView imageView= (ImageView).dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogimageview);
    URL url = new URL("http://image10.bizrate-images.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    dialog.show();
}
```

customdialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialogimageview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I know this method but want to do it without defining a new xml

Comment: you want with out layout

Comment: Yes. I want it without layout. Don't know what is problem with my code

Comment: create custom layout with coding

Comment: LinearLayout ss=new LinearLayout(this);
            ImageView dialog=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            dialog.setImageBitmap(yourimgage);
            ss.addView(dialog);

Answer (score 0):

Use need use `setContentView` : [Dialog custom layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
```

Comment: Yeah I can do that but instead of defining a new layout file just wanted a image in the dailog. Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh! Try this. http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/imageview-with-loading-spinner-t49439.html
or checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351204/android-progressdialog-with-setcontentview .

Answer (score 0):

```
imgvw.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_launcher);
```

try this if it renders then there is some problem in the uri

Comment: can you post the value of   **descImgOne**

Answer (score 0):

One of the working code (using web view inside the dialog)

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

WebView wv = new WebView(this);
wv.loadUrl("http://www.jjyproductions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/IMG_3454-001.jpg");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

     view.loadUrl(url);
     return true;

   }    
});

   wv.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

   alert.setView(wv);

   alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
  });
  alert.show();
```